# Whose job is it to track down the source of a noise?

Tags: noise, usa, sounds, vibration

I've been living in a new apartment for a few weeks and on the third night a loud hum that vibrates the floor started. The noise hasn't stopped since and I want to locate the source so I can inform the manager. The DIY solutions I found online are too complicated and expensive (I don't want to spend three or four digits on microphones I'll never use again, I don't want to build anything, etc.) so I want to hire someone instead. Whose job is it to track a noise to the source? I'm only asking the name of this sort of job and I live in the USA.

Comment: I would think it is the managers/building maintenance to find and fix the problem.  If the hum is constant it should be a bit easier if it is in the building.  They should also know if any work was done in that time frame.

Comment: Be aware that it _may_ be a problem with your hearing rather than the building.

Comment: What is below your apartment?  If it's another apartment, could it be that someone turned on a poorly balanced ceiling fan that's vibrating the ceiling of their unit, and the floor of yours?  If there is a unit below yours, you could check with your downstairs neighbor and see if they have a ceiling fan, and if it's on.  From there, it should be pretty easy to deduce if the fan is the source of the vibration, and if so, an easy conversation with your landlord to get it fixed.